How to submit the folder contents by Rsync with SSL keys protected by the passphrase?
After has been recommended to stop to use Git for deploying to VPS, I have returned to Rsync method.
Unfortunatly Rsync is very unfrendly, emits the unclear errors and sometime the error message does not matching with what actually wrong. So, am not expecting that you will answer what
rsync: Failed to exec r: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]

means.
First what I need to check in the syntax.
I have VPS with Ubuntu 22.04 and WSL with Ubuntu 20.04.
Following the basic security requirements, in VPS I have:

Created the non-root users
Created the SSH keys with passphrases
Disabled the logging in by the password for any users
Fully disabled the logging in for root user

Now I need to deploy the contents of local 04-StagingBuild directory to var/www/staging.example.com of VPS. Unfortunately, I have not found the "unified correct syntax". This version
rsync -azver -i ~/.ssh/Example-Deployer ./04-StagingBuild/ Deployer@1XX.XX.XX.XX0:/var/www/staging.example.com

causes
rsync: Failed to exec r: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]

There is also version with --rsh=ssh
rsync -azver --rsh=ssh -i~/.ssh/Example-Deployer ./04-StagingBuild/ Deployer@1XX.XX.XX.XX0:/var/www/staging.example.com

It causes
Deployer@1XX.XX.XX.XX0: Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]

I can't post actual terminal output because of sensitive information, but I am sure that all directories are existing. Also, normal SSH logging in works fine.
If you need me check something please let me know - I'll provide as much details as possible.

Why are you using those specific options for rsync? What do you think the -i does? Or the -e? What do you actually want your rsync to do?

And what is Example-Deployer?

Thank you for the comments and answer. "Why are you using those specific options for rsync?" - because, AFAIK, it is impossible to submit the data to VPS by Rsync without these options if VPS required the authentication by SSL. "What do you actually want your rsync to do? " - exactly according the question title, to submit the files to VPS by Rsync using the SSL keys with passphrases.

@terdon, "And what is Example-Deployer?" - The name of private SSL key file where Example is the site/app name and Deployer - the name of users (seems to be the authority role, but the names like "Jonh" make no sense for which purposes this user has been granted the access to VPS). When multiple developers need the access to VPS, I am using [Site/AppName]-[FullName]-[Role] naming scheme, for example, Foo-TakeshiTokugawa-Admin. Some constructive criticism? =)

The options you have used don't make sense, certainly not the -i and probably not the -e, so if my answer isn't what you need, please [edit] the question and describe the behavior you expect from rsync.

@terdon Your answer was perfect. Thank you again!

The -e option for rsync is (from man rsync):
--rsh=COMMAND, -e        specify the remote shell to use

[...]

--rsh=COMMAND, -e
   This  option  allows  you  to  choose  an alternative remote shell
   program to use for communication between the local and remote
   copies of rsync.  Typically, rsync is configured to use ssh by default, 
   but you may prefer to use rsh on a local network.

This means that it expects a value. And you are using -azver so -e sees r as the value and tries to execute it. Since there is no program called r, it fails.
And the -i option is
       --itemize-changes, -i    output a change-summary for all updates

So -i ~/.ssh/Example-Deployer makes no sense. It looks like you are using command line options from another program. I suspect you are thinking of the -i option of ssh, but that isn't what -i means in rsync. Remember, each tool has its own options and you should never assume the meaning is the same.
Now, if ~/.ssh/Example-Deployer is a key file that you want to use, you might try:
rsync -azvr -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/Example-Deployer" \
  ./04-StagingBuild/ Deployer@1XX.XX.XX.XX0:/var/www/staging.example.com

However, the details will depend on exactly what behavior you want. If you update the question and explain what you want rsync to do, I can update if the above isn't enough.

Thank you for the answer! Your solution works perfectly.
